# Linker problem linking boost in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, boost, linker

I have a rather obscure linking problem in Visual Studio 2008. The linker error message is: "LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_38.lib'". All pathes and dependencies are set.
What I noticed though is that Visual Studio misses boost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_38.lib and not **libboost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_38.lib** (notice the lib at the beginning of the file name). I added the .lib as libboost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_38.lib to the project and it appears as libboost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_38.lib in the command line.

Why does Visual Studio the beginning of the file name?

Answer (score 1):

There is a rule for naming libraries in Boost:

1) boost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_38.lib for dynamically linked version
2) libboost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_38.lib for statically linked version

`BOOST_LIB_PREFIX:     "lib" for static libraries otherwise "".`

There is a preprocessor define that you can define in your project in order to use the dynamically linked version of a boost library `BOOST_DYN_LINK=1`

It has this description:

`BOOST_DYN_LINK:           Optional: when set link to dll rather than static library.`

Another define that tells to use the dynamic version of Boost.Thread is `BOOST_THREAD_USE_DLL`

Comment: thank you, somewhere deep inside the project there was a symbol set to use the dll.