# How boost knows which LIB to link with and how to change it?

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use boost::thread.

When I try to compile my project (VS2010), the linker cannot find lib named "libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_47.lib".

- The first thing I cannot understand is how does boost decides the lib name it needs to link to? I searched the boost code for that string, but I couldn't find any. Where does this name comes from?
- If I place the requested lib, everything works fine using the boost DLL, but I want to statically link to the libraries, therefore I have "libboost_thread-vc100-mt-s-1_47.lib" which I want to link to, but boost looks for the other file. How can I make boost link to this file so I will be able to work statically?

Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: It builds up these strings gradually in various configuration headers, then does a pragma comment lib. Will provide a full answer if nobody else does; a little busy right now.

Comment: [This might help for statically linking boost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560983/linker-problem-linking-boost-in-visual-studio-2008)

Comment: @Borgleader - I checked it out, but it doesn't help because the problem is not the "prefix" but the "-s-" in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - The first thing I cannot understand is how does boost decides the lib
>     name it needs to link to? I searched the boost code for that string,
>     but I couldn't find any. Where does this name comes from?

This is auto-link feature. You can see how boost composes the names of the libraries being linked in `boost/config/auto_link.hpp` header.

> - If I place the requested lib, everything works fine using the boost
>     DLL, but I want to statically link to the libraries

Make sure that you link with the CRT statically (Project properties --> C++ --> Code generation --> Runtime library... should be /MT or /MTd). Then boost will be auto-linked statically as well.